# iText and Digital Signature

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, digital-signature

I trying create a signature in pdf using iText for JAVA and Portuguese Citizen Card (Smart Card). But when code execute MakeSignature class i receive always an error saying:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance

I need some help here, can anyone help me?

```
 try {
        String pkcs11Config = "name=GemPC" + "\n" + "library=C:/WINDOWS/system32/pteidpkcs11.dll";
        ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
        Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);

        Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
        CallbackHandler cmdLineHdlr = new DialogCallbackHandler();

        KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11Provider,
                new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(cmdLineHdlr));

        KeyStore ks = builder.getKeyStore();

        PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdf, fos, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setReason("I'm the author");

        String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();

        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE", null);
        Certificate chain = ks.getCertificate(alias);

        X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) chain;
        x509.checkValidity();

        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        Certificate[] certs = new Certificate[1];
        certs[0] = chain;

        MakeSignature.signDetached(sap, digest, es, certs, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        return dest;
    } catch (CertificateExpiredException | CertificateNotYetValidException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Signer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: All the samples i see to implement this feature using Portuguese Citizen Card is made with null password. And this work with iText 5.2 but not work in iText5.5 because API changes. I tested with SHA1 hash algoritm because all samples use it.

Comment: You're correct, I answered too quickly. The password is entered at a later stage with PKCS#11.

Comment: SHA1 is the standard for Portuguese Citizen Card. It uses a SHA1 RSA encryption. I confirmed.

Comment: It works with the Belgian card and  I don't have a Portuguese card to test with, so I can't reproduce the problem. If I can't reproduce the problem, I can't help you. You'll have to ask somebody in Portugal to find out which encryption algorithm is supported by the smart card. According to the error message that is thrown by Java (not by iText), it's not an RSA key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your private key in a smartcard (PKCS11) you cannot wrapp this key in a java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey because your key material is in a secure device.

So probably you must change the provider in your code:

```
 ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1", "BC");
```

for:

```
 ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1", pkcs11Provider.getName());
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes its works, but is signature is not authenticated, maybe have same think in fault.

Comment: I'm not understand your comment, what do you mean when you say "is signature is not authenticated"?

Comment: Sorry. Acrobat says my signature can't authenticated.

Comment: If you want to validate with acrobat you have to add the issuer CA of your certificate to acrobat configuration. You can do this following the next steps: Validate the signature from acrobat and then when adobe says that is invalid, access to the signature properties, select signer tag and click on "show certificate" button then you see the certificate validation path, you have to select the issuer CA certificate and in the "trust" tag click on "Add to Trusted identities..." button, then you can validate the signature again and this time must be valid.

Comment: Yes its true ;) I reading manual of Poruguese Citizen Card and i see it. Thanks for confirmation. You are BIG ;)